# Route logged in user to profile on all request to <front> node

Tags: 7, routes, rules

I'm attempting to make a simple login page on the front page that once you log in it will route you to your profile. This part I got working with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but if the user clicks the home link on the site at any point, when logged in, I want to route the user to the profile, not the front page.

I tried a similar trigger to the one I got routing a user when they log in. This being on page view trigger *when role is not anonymous* and URL alias is `/node` route to `user/[account:uid]`

When logged in I click the home button and it's not getting triggered. It just sends me to the homepage.

How can I do this with Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's some missing detail (e.g. checking the right alias, token data not available, etc.).

A simple way to do this to do a page redirect action on a *Drupal is initializing* event with conditions, *Data comparison*  on `[site:current-page:path]` & negated *User has role(s)* on `[site:current-user]`. Then you can check for the Drupal path that's set for your front page (i.e. '/node').

For example:

```
{ "rules_login_frontpage_redirect" : {
    "LABEL" : "Logged in Frontpage Redirect to Profile Page",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "node" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "user\/[site:current-user:uid]" } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a page that explains in detail about this example you have?
I just want to know how this works so I can build more complex rules as needed.

Comment: This example looks to work but I don't understand why it works.

Comment: The rule says, *IF:* the internal requested path is `/node` & the user isn't anonymous on boot up *THEN:* redirect the current user page, Note, that setting an alias, & setting a path as the front page are two different things. This rule works because `/node` is set as the default home page. The actual rule path would need to change if it was set to something different.